# Text Block and image over a image

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to get result as shown in picture one but when I am coding it shows as I want by setting up margin left and right on images. It shows same result on some resolutions but not friendly in all resolution. I need a resolution friendly layout, please tell me how can i achieve this:

[image]

My code is

```css
/* Slider */

.slider-bg {
  background-image: url("http://www.design.earnandearn.com/zx-content/themes/default/media/img/grownstar-custom/slider_bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #E1B706;
  height: 415px;
}
.container {
  height: 415px;
  max-width: 1030px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.man {
  height: 415px;
  width: 542px;
  background-image: url(http://www.design.earnandearn.com/zx-content/themes/default/media/img/grownstar-custom/man.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
}
.sliderright {
  float: left;
  height: 344px;
}
.sliderright h3 {
  font-size: 39px;
  color: #6e8d30;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.sliderright h2 {
  color: #7b33ad;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.sliderright p {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.sliderright a.btn {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #bae23d;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000000;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: none;
  width: 150px;
}
.sliderright small {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sliderright">
      <h3>Making Your Extra Money with</h3>
      <h2>Our Social Network</h2>
      <p>
        <small>Achieve your dream for the financial freedom !</small>
        Earn money Anywhere and Anytime
      </p>
      <a class="btn btn-warning" href="register.php">Signup Now !</a>

      <div class="man"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My CSS file , not know how to add above http://www.design.earnandearn.com/zx-content/themes/default/media/css/home.css

Comment: You need to create a demo with absolute image paths. Relative paths will not work in code snippets.

Comment: http://www.design.earnandearn.com/zx-content/themes/default/media/img/grownstar-custom/man.png

http://www.design.earnandearn.com/zx-content/themes/default/media/img/grownstar-custom/slider_bg.jpg

Comment: @HoriyaBatool.. firstly try these links for  your code snippet "http://www.design.earnandearn.com/zx-content/themes/default/media/img/grownstar-custom/man.png" and "http://www.design.earnandearn.com/zx-content/themes/default/media/img/grownstar-custom/slider_bg.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Just add `top: 0;` to your class ".man".

Like:

```
.man {
  height: 415px;
  width: 542px;
  background-image: url(../img/grownstar-custom/man.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  top: 0,
}
```

Tipp: If you put the image with an `<img>` [tag](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/HTML/Multimedia_und_Grafiken/Grafiken) right into your .man div you don't need any height and width settings. The img will stretch it automatically.

And you should not name the class "man". Its not a man... Its a woman, I think.

Comment: Thanks , image goes up but still not resolution friendly. I want class man will be with text. for do this i creat a more div in which i set max with 1030px. i want to show than both in same div but its not showing . in given situation if i add margin right and get my results but its works on some some result ion with same result not with others .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<div class="slider-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sliderright">
      <h3>Making Your Extra Money with</h3>
      <h2>Our Social Network</h2>
      <p>
        <small>Achieve your dream for the financial freedom !</small>
        Earn money Anywhere and Anytime
      </p>
      <a class="btn btn-warning" href="register.php">Signup Now !</a>


    </div>
       <div class="man" style="float:right;margin:-21px 6px 2px 9px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Set your image `man`class div out from the `sliderright`class div and give a margin to it.

See :- [JSFiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/Harpreet_devgun/9d39z4eo/)

**Update 1**:-
   Set property`position: relative;` for both `.container` and `.sliderright` classes. See this updated code [JSFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/Harpreet_devgun/9d39z4eo/3/).
Hope this will help you!

Comment: I want to add class "man" in my class "container" I want when veiwer see web text and image not change. If i added margin to my class man than it will change position with every resolution